# Как правильно написать условие на проверку массива

Tags: javascript

Функция `isSorted`, которая получает массив чисел `boxNumbers` и возвращает `true`, если все числа расположены в порядке возрастания, или `false` – если нет.

Как правильно написать условие на проверку массива?

```js
function isSorted(boxNumbers) {

  let prev = 0;
  let curr = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < boxNumbers.length; i++) {

    curr = boxNumbers[i]
    if (curr < prev) {
      return false
    } else if (curr >= prev) {
      prev = curr
    }
  }
}
let result = isSorted([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]);
console.log(result)




isSorted([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // true
isSorted([0, 1, 1, 1, 2]); // true
isSorted([1, 2, 11]); // true
isSorted([5]); // true
isSorted([]); // true
isSorted([0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2]); // false
isSorted([1, 11, 2]); // false
```

Comment: и что не получается?

Answer (score 5):

Если лишнее убрать:

```
function isSorted(boxNumbers) {
 
  for (let i = 1; i < boxNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (boxNumbers[i] < boxNumbers[i-1]) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: Вот так сработало, скажите пожалуйста  boxNumbers[i-1] это как последующий элемент? Я стараюсь писать всё максимально в ручную что бы развивать алгоритмизацию=)

Comment: Нет, предыдущий

Comment: @VladyslavTymoshenko `boxNumbers[i-1]` здесь является предыдущим относительно текущего элементом. Если предыдущий элемент больше текущего, то массив не отсортирован

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!

Answer (score 3):

Да вроде всё написано что надо... Только в конце функции добавить `return true;` надо, если проверка на `false` ни разу не прошла

Comment: isSorted([5]); // true
isSorted([]); // true
 Эти тесты не проходит

Comment: если опираться на то, что написано в вопросе (true , true  для этих случаев), то всё проходит как надо.... если дописать то, что я написал.......

Comment: Как Вы сказали, всё сработало у меня локально, а на тесты закидывал, то ругалось.

Comment: Видимо тесты ожидают чего-то другого ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯    может они должны быть там false всё же....т.к. пустой массив - это не отсортированная последовательность чисел явно

Comment: Ладно, главное что понимание задачи пришло, спасибо!